# Python: matplotlib does not show edges between nodes

Tags: python

I have a network defined as a csr sparse matrix. There are 986 nodes, and only two edges (between nodes 80 and 409, and nodes 80 and 891). I'm trying to visualize this graph (and others). Right now, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pdf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

if __name__=='__main__':


        hour_dense = np.zeros((986, 986))
        hour_dense[80, 409] = 1
        hour_dense[80, 891] = 1
        hour_1 = sparse.csr_matrix(hour_dense)

        edges = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(hour_1)
        options = {
            'node_color': 'black',
            'node_size': 3,
            'line_color': 'red',
            'linewidths': 1,
            'edge_color':'red',
            'width': 0.1,
        }
        nx.draw(edges, **options)
        plt.savefig('train_graph_hour_1.png')
```

The result is this:

[image]

**Question: Why does this not show the edges between the vertices, and how can I make it show the two edges?**

Comment: Note: this works fine as long as there are very few vertices. I tried with 10 vertices and everything showed up.

Comment: Why they don't show: the edges are there but the connected nodes are drawn too close together. How to fix it? I'm afraid I don't know, besides manually specifying node positions.